Equivalency between integration methods when there's a delta function at the boundary
In class, we solved the following equation,
$$\mu\frac{\partial \psi(x,\mu)}{\partial x} + \Sigma\psi(x,\mu) = \frac{S_0}{2}\delta(x)$$
where $S_0$ and $\Sigma$ are constants, $0 \le x \le a$, $-1 \le \mu \le 1$.
We solved it by putting the source term as the boundary condition $\psi(0,\mu)=\frac{S_0}{2}$, and solving the homogeneous system,
$$\mu\frac{\partial \psi(x,\mu)}{\partial x} + \Sigma\psi(x,\mu) = 0$$
which results in
$$\psi(x,\mu) = \psi(0,\mu)e^{-\frac{\Sigma}{\mu}x}$$
which after applying the BC, gives a final solution of
$$\psi(x,\mu) = \frac{S_0}{2}e^{-\frac{\Sigma}{\mu}x}.$$
However, I tried to solve the inhomogeneous problem directly using Laplace transforms (and the BC $\psi(0,\mu) = 0$), which gave me the following result,
$$\mu[s\Psi(s,\mu) - \psi(0,\mu)] + \Sigma\Psi(s,\mu) = \frac{S_0}{2}e^{-t}$$
$$\mu[s - (-\frac{\Sigma}{\mu})]\Psi(s,\mu) = \frac{S_0}{2}e^{-t}$$
$$\Psi(s,\mu) = \frac{S_0}{2}\frac{1}{\mu[s - (-\frac{\Sigma}{\mu})]}e^{-t}.$$
Then applying the inverse Laplace transform, I arrived at the solution,
$$\psi(x,\mu)=\frac{S_0}{2\mu}e^{-\frac{\Sigma}{\mu}x}u(x).$$
These solutions differ by a factor of $\frac{1}{\mu}$ which is present in the Laplace solution but not in the homogenous + BC solution. I was under the impression that the different methods should give the same result for the equation. Looking at textbooks for this problem, the answer they cite is the one produced by the Laplace approach.
Any thoughts on what is wrong and how to reconcile these approaches?

The units seem to be different in both answers. Perhaps some dimensional analysis can shed light on which one is correct. I don't see how the delta function at $0$ implies that BC from your class example though...

@whpowell96 As was explained to me, physically (in the context of neutron transport), the delta function is supposed to represent that this is a point source of magnitude S/2 at x=0, which is why it was appropriate to set the flux (psi) to be S/2 at the x=0 boundary.
